# How to insert Form in Gridextension typo3?

Tags: php, forms, typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-gridelements

I'm using TYPO3 9.5 and I'm trying to insert Form inside Grid elements (using gridelements extension)  :
I am using :

```
"require": {
    "typo3/cms-base-distribution": "^9.5",
    "gridelementsteam/gridelements": "^9.3",
    "mask/mask": "^4.1",
    "ichhabrecht/mask-export": "^2.4",
},
```

So the grid column work fine in the Frontend and the content is displaying, the only Problem is with **the form which is not displayed in the Frontend** (if I put it inside the grid column)

Backend Grid elements : [image: Grid elements in the Backend]
Frontend Grid element when I debug all data :[image: Debug grid data] 
Thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the form is based on a flexform you should disable the matching parameter in the setup of that particular gridelement.

```
dataProcessing {
    10 = GridElementsTeam\Gridelements\DataProcessing\GridChildrenProcessor
    10 {
        default {
            as = children
            # Default options of the grid children processor
            # Change them according to the needs of your layout
            # Read more about it in the TypoScript section of the manual
            options {
            #    sortingDirection = ASC
            #    sortingField = sorting
            #    recursive = 0
            resolveFlexFormData = 0
            #    resolveBackendLayout = 1
            #    respectColumns = 1
            #    respectRows = 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally there is a feature request to disable flexform resolving for child elements other than gridelements.

https://gitlab.com/coderscare/gridelements/issues/14

Answer (score 0):

you should check your static includes (typoscript). i know this problem from wrong configurations in the past.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I checked and nothing change  :(